# How to customize FileInputFormat to read multiple lines of a file in Java when using Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using MapReduce framework in Java, and I want to create a customized file input format.
Suppose my file format is something like:
--------------
**$-flag-$**
what
I
really
want
**$-flag-$**
and
another
part
---------------
In this case, each record is seen as an array of multiple lines. 
Followed the tutorial, I wrote this:

```
public class CustomInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text, IdxValues> {
    public RecordReader<Text, IdxValues> getRecordReader(
            InputSplit input, JobConf job, Reporter report) throws IOException {

        report.setStatus(input.toString());
        return new CustomReader(job, (FileSplit)input);
    } 
}
```

Now I wonder how I should implement the **CustomReader** class, to read [*what I really want*] and [*and another part*] as two arrays separately?

Comment: Is your flag a character or expression?

Comment: @rVr It's an URI that's surrounded by a constant string, e.g, '$-C:/usr/john-$'. for each record, there is a unique URI. It should work as a delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

I already did something like that.Here I have '$$$' as delimiter(I made it pass as a configuration parameter to job). You can check the code [here](https://github.com/thomachan/Custom-MR/tree/master/src/mapreduce/hi/api/generic/input) and for its concrete implementaion [here](https://github.com/thomachan/Custom-MR/tree/master/src/mapreduce/hi/api/input/defaultcustom) on the same project. I customized RecordReader as well as InputFormat.